# Setting debug=False causes markup to fail in mezzanine

Tags: debugging, http-status-code-404, markup, mezzanine

I'm encountering a strange error using flat in mezzanine. I've modified none of the source other than to remove future, but when I set mezzanine debug mode to False it fails to fetch most of the markup files, returning a 404 for them. I must admit, I am completely puzzled on this one. It seems to be a file permissions problem, but what is triggering it and how to fix?

Comment: What are markup files?

Comment: it returns 404 on many css and js files. It seems to be within the Django structure itself. But this out of the box install is so basic, I can't imagine this being either unusual or some sort of newbie mistake. Searching for various error keywords have been fruitless.

Comment: Sounds like a django newbie mistake to me. When`DEBUG=False`, the *development server* does not serve static assets. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/.

Comment: Exactly what I was hoping to hear. Thanks for your insight.